# ffmpeg writes invalid HLS video length

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using ffmpeg to generate a hls file as follows:

```
ffmpeg 
   -i input.mp4 
   -y -preset slow 
   -c:v h264 
   -g 48 -keyint_min 48 
   -sc_threshold 0 
   -profile:v main 
   -crf 25 
   -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 128k 
   -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod 
   -hls_segment_filename temp.%d.ts 
   -master_pl_name temp.v%v.m3u8 
   -shortest 
   tempName2.m3u8
```

This works, however the video displays wrong end in the iOS avplayer (works correctly in VLC and Quicktime).

The original video is here:

https://storage.googleapis.com/easyeasy-assets-devel/challenges/nem-kri-nfns/mayo-1/step-1.mp4

The processed video is here:

https://storage.googleapis.com/easyeasy-assets-devel/challenges/nem-kri-nfns/mayo-1/processed/step-1.m3u8

The last file of the hls chunk is this:

https://storage.googleapis.com/easyeasy-assets-devel/challenges/nem-kri-nfns/mayo-1/processed/step-1.1.ts

When probing with ffmpeg I can see this:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'tempName.1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:03.26, start: 7.176000, bitrate: 1901 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1920, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 118 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 1080x1920, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 wrapped_avframe
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 pcm_s16le
frame=   80 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:03.28 bitrate=N/A speed=28.7x
```

Note the:

```
  Duration: 00:00:03.26, start: 7.176000, bitrate: 1901 kb/s
```

and then:

```
frame=   80 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:03.28 bitrate=N/A speed=28.7x
```

With ffprobe, I see something completely else:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'tempName.1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:03.26, start: 7.176000, bitrate: 1901 kb/s
...
[FORMAT]
...
duration=3.264000
```

What am I doing wrong? The `-shortest` parameter does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: *video displays wrong end in the iOS avplayer* --> can you clarify?

Comment: With avplayer the video ends with a gray frame which is not within the original video. VLC and Quicktime does not show this last gray frame for some reason. However primarily I need it to work with the Apple's avplayer.

Comment: @Gyan can you at least point me in a direction where to look?

Comment: Unequal stream duration, the audio is likely longer. It can also be mismatched timestamps. Check with ffprobe.

Comment: I have already checked with ffprobe, see above. I am just not sure what I do about it: the `-shortest` seems to have no effect here.

Comment: Stream duration, not format duration.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/aca116a7ae0ba9b9aea8a23acf55ba39

ffprobe doesn't seem to state different lenghts here. Is there some parameter I should use?

Comment: Can you specify how should I call ffprobe to get the output you describe? @gyan See the gist above with my output.

Comment: `ffprobe file -v 0 -show_entries stream=duration -of compact`

Comment: the lengths differ - so is there something I can do to make it do them equal? Note the `-shortest` parameter was used: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/de2f3638b108246a3ca2c7d542b8bf52

Comment: @Gyan can you please elaborate?